# EMGU: BayerGB 8bit to Image<Bgr, byte>

Tags: c#, opencv, colors

I have a byte array generate from a camera.
I want to convert this c# array (*byte[] myBuffer*) to a Emgu BgrImage.

The RAW image from the camera has 2590 x 1940 pixel.
The format is the BayerGB 8bit, so there are 2590(cols) x 1940(rows) x 2(byte) = 10059560 bytes.

I grab the data form the camera and I have a byte array with the data

```
byte[] myBuffer = myGrabberFuncion();
//myBuffer.lenght == 10059560
```

now I want to convert it to a BGR Image. I think I should use the ***Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvtColor(SRC, DEST, COLOR_CONV, CHANN )*** function.

But i can't feed the function with a byte[] as the SRC argument, as it needs a "IInputArray".

So I can feed in a **Mat**, or a **Matrix**, or an **Image<# , #>**

But how should I put "buffer" data in to one of this structures?

If I use `Matrix< byte > Bayer = new new ecv.Matrix<byte>(rows, cols, channels)` I can't set 1 channel, because it would contain half the bytes of  **myBuffer**

I can't set it to 2 channels, because an "assert" of the Opencv tells me that the color conversion `CvEnum.ColorConversion.BayerGb2Bgr` wants a 1-channel input image (it tells: `OpenCV: scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4)`)

I tried, as a work-around, to make a image  with double width and convert this image, this don't give an error, but the output image is black (all zeroes)

```
byte[] buffer = myGrabberFunction();

Image<Structure.Bgr, byte> lastFrameBgr = new Image<Structure.Bgr, byte>(2590, 1942);

//test with Matrix of bytes:
ecv.Matrix<byte> bayerMatrix = new ecv.Matrix<byte>(lastFrameBgr.Height, lastFrameBgr.Rows, 2);
bayerMatrix.Bytes = buffer;
ecv.CvInvoke.CvtColor(bayerMatrix, lastFrameBgr, ecv.CvEnum.ColorConversion.BayerGb2Bgr, 3);
//result in a black Image


//test with an 1 channel Byte depth image   
Image<Structure.Gray, byte> bayerGrayImage = new Image<Structure.Gray, byte>(lastFrameBgr.Width * 2, lastFrameBgr.Height);
bayerGrayImage.Bytes = buffer;
ecv.CvInvoke.CvtColor(bayerGrayImage, lastFrameBgr, ecv.CvEnum.ColorConversion.BayerGb2Bgr, 3);
//result in a black Image
```

My Question:
How can i transform my array of bytes in something i can use as source in Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvtColor(... ) funcion?

Or How should I do to convert am array of bytes into a Emgu Bgr Image?